# Blender → Unity: Getting wrong Edges/Border?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, blender, mesh, 3d-modelling

Im testing some stuff on my HoloLens and wanted to put a cube-edge-shader on my objects, which I created in Blender. This objects are just some stretched cubes. I saw in the MRTK-Example package a good example for a wireframe and tried to apply it on my .fbx-models.

This is how it looks like in the example:
[image]

Than I took my model and applied the same settings, but it looks different (on the right you see the model without any changes):
[image]

Does sb know why this happens? I guess there are some wrong import settings in unity? In Blender I unwrapped the cubes

Comment: What happens when you export a square cube and try the material on that?

Comment: the same problem